# Prove, for all integers $n \geq 6$, $n^n>2^n n!$.

Tags: number-theory, inequality, induction, exponential-function, factorial

I tried method of induction. Assuming its true for $n=k$, i.e. $k^k > 2^k k!$.
To prove, $(k+1)^{(k+1)} > 2^{k+1} (k+1)!$. 
I started with, $$\begin{align}2^{k+1}(k+1)! &= 2^k 2 (k+1) k! \\
&< k^k 2 (k+1) \\
&< k^k k (k+1) \\
&= k^{(k+1)}(k+1) \\
&< (k+1)^{(k+1)} (k+1)\\
& = (k+1)^{(k+2)}\end{align}$$ but I need to end up at $(k+1)^{(k+1)}$.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $n=6$ we need to prove that $$6^6>2^66!$$ or
$$3^6>6!$$ or
$$729>720.$$

If $n^n>2^nn!$ then we obtain:
$$(n+1)^{n+1}=\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n(n+1)n^n>\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n(n+1)2^nn!.$$
Thus, it's enough to prove that
$$\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n(n+1)2^nn!>2^{n+1}(n+1)!$$ or
$$\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n>2,$$ which is obvious for $n\geq6$.

Answer (score 1):

$$(n+1)^{n+1}>2^{n+1}(n+1)!$$

$$(n+1)^{n}>2^{n+1}(n)!$$

$$\frac 1 2 (n+1)^{n} >2^{n}(n)!$$

By hypothesis of induction we have that $n^n> 2^n n!$

$$\frac 1 2 (n+1)^{n} >n^n>2^{n}(n)!$$

$$( \frac {n+1}{n})^n>2$$

Which is true for $n>2$ since :

$$2\leq (1+\frac 1 n)^n<e$$